# Basic Simulink Block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a matrix [1*4] and another matrix [1*4].  I want to combine this two matrix in the order of result [2*4] or [4*2] but not in the order of [1*8]. Which Simulink block to do this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [***Matrix Concatenate***](https://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/vectorconcatenate.html) block [image: **]